# IOS Objective-C use the Swift pod files

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I want to use the Pod for my project. I found the pod. But it swift. I want to use that pod to my Objective-C project.

this is the pod file link
https://github.com/vikmeup/SCLAlertView-Swift

I want to know how we can use the swift pod to objective-c?
is it possible to use swift pod to objective-C?

Comment: You need to provide more information. As it stands it would be impossible for someone to help you here. For starters, what is the pod you're having an issue with? What is the contents of your Podfile, how have you tried calling the swift methods? Do you get any compiler errors? Are you targeting any build lower that iOS 7.0?

Comment: @squarefrog now I modified the question.

Comment: It is in theory possible to use a Swift pod in a regular Objective-C project, but I suspect you need to learn Swift and "get in bed" with it (and also maybe learn more about pod internals) to do this.  Even using a regular Objective-C pod is often not straight-forward.